# Restricting a sample on a multiply imputed variable

Tags: stata, missing-data, multiple-imputation

Apologies if this is more of a statistical question.

I am currently dealing with a multiple imputation problem that I am attempting to address in Stata. After the imputation stage, I would like to estimate $E(Y, X, Z | C=1)$ where $Y$ and $Z$ are complete and $X$ and $C$ are both incomplete variables whose missing values are multiply imputed.

In Stata, my multiple imputation command is:

```
mi impute chained ///
(logit)  C ///
(regress) X = Y X1 X2 X3 X4, ///
 add(5) augment noisily rseed(123)
```

And my post-imputation estimation command is:

```
mi estimate, esampvaryok post: regress Y X Z if C==1
```

I use esampvaryok to force estimation. By default Stata returns an error when estimation sample varies across multiply imputed datasets. This will happen here since the conditioning variable, C, is imputed, and the distribution of imputed values varies by imputation.

Even with esampvaryok specified, Stata returns the following warning:

> Warning: estimation sample varies across imputations; results may be biased.
>            Sample sizes vary between 643 and 680.

While concerning, my substantive research question requires that $C=1$ for estimation. As an oversimplification of my problem, $Y$ represents an asthma diagnosis, $X$ is a summary of patient reports of respiratory breathing difficulty, and $X$ is obese status. The assertion is that breathing difficulty (or other asthma symptoms) may be more apparent in obese children, even without asthma. Thus, in obese populations, breathing difficulty alone cannot be used to diagnose asthma.

I am wondering if there are any papers that tackle this specific question, or if anyone has any recommendations for how to proceed in cases like this one.

Thank you,

Paul